# Lookup for a key in dictionary with... regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary that have the following structure: The key is a link between a source and a destination, the value is the instance of an object wire.

```
wire_dict = { source1_destination1_1 : object,
              source1_destination1_2 : object
              source2_destination1_3 : object
              source2_destination1_4 : object
              source2_destination2_1 : object
              source2_destination2_2 : object }
```

Let's suppose that I only have a destination value, and with that I want to find, perhaps with regular expressions, the key that have the `destination1_1`. As you can see, same sources can have several destinations, but different sources cannot have the same destinations. So I want to find the key that **ends with the destination**.

Since the wire_dict could contain a lot of key-value entries, please tell me how this approach can affect the performance of the application. Perhaps I should create another dictionary only for the relationship between source and destination?

**UPDATE**: I change the dictionary with tuples as keys:

```
wire_dict = { ('source1','destination1_1') : object1,
              ('source1','destination1_2') : object2
              ('source2','destination1_3') : object3
              ('source2','destination1_4') : object4
              ('source2','destination2_1') : object5
              ('source2','destination2_2') : object6 }
```

The logic of the application is the same. A destination cannot have more than one source. So, only a coincidence should be found when a destination is provided.

Comment: Your data organization doesn't support this operation efficiently... You should really follow progo advice and use pairs instead of a string. Moreover if you keep track of which sources are associated to a destination you'd be able to do obtain the result you want without scanning all entries.

Comment: @Bakuriu I edited the post. See update above.

Answer (score 3):

Having string searches through dict keys is going to be linear time with standard python dictionaries. But it can be done with `dict.keys()` and `re` module as @avim helpfully told.

For the second concern, instead of string keys, how about having tuples as keys:

```
{(begin, end): connection_object}
```

It won't speed up at all (search is likely stay linear) but it enables better code behind the logic you want to express.

Comment: I already set up tuples as keys as you suggested:
`{('source_1', 'destination_1'): 'object1'}` .
However, the problem is almost the same. I need to find a key, any coincidence, just by providing, for example 'destination_1'. I'm very sure that there will be only one coincidence, The logic of the app is destinations only have one source.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
wire_dict = {'source1_destination1_1' : 'object1',
              'source1_destination1_2' : 'object2',
              'source2_destination1_3' : 'object3',
              'source2_destination1_4' : 'object4',
              'source2_destination2_1' : 'object5',
              'source2_destination2_2' : 'object6' }
pattern = 'source1_destination1_1'
print [value for key, value in wire_dict.items() if re.search(pattern, key)]
```

Output:

```
['object1']
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need `str.endswith` and to iterate over the dict checking each key.

```
print([k for k in wire_dict if k.endswith("destination1_1")])
```

If there is only over one use next and a generator expression:

```
k = next((k for k in wire_dict if k.endswith("destination1_1")),"")
```

If you want the value use `wire_dict.get(k)` in case there is no match and you get an empty string returned from the next call.

```
In [18]: k = next((k for k in wire_dict if k.endswith("destination1_1")),"")

In [19]: wire_dict[k]
Out[19]: object

In [20]: k
Out[20]: 'source1_destination1_1'
```

You should also never use `dict.keys` in python2 unless you actually want a list. You can simply iterate over the dict object to access each key efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to run over all dict keys and find the ones that match your pattern, but it's slow for big dicts.

I think you need another dict with keys matching your destinations (as you thought).

Answer (score 0):

**O**bject **o**riented **p**rogramming my friend

```
class Uberdict():
    def init(source, destination, obj):
        self.source, self.destination, self.obj = source, destination, obj

    def has_destination(destination)
        # True or False
        return self.desination == destination

    def has_source(source)
        return self.source == source

wire_object_list = [
    # list of the objects
]
# how to create them
example_obj = Uberdict(some_source, some_destination, some_instance)
wire_object_list.append(example_obj)

# filter
example_destination = 'some destination'
filtered_list = [item for item in wire_object_list if item.has_destination(example_destination)
```

*only psuedo code could have errors*